# If $|f(z)|\lt a|q(z)|$ for some $a\gt 0$, then $f=bq$ for some $b\in \mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $q\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is a polynomial, $f\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is analytic on all of $\mathbb{C}$, and if there exists $a\gt 0$ such that  $|f(z)| \lt  a|q(z)|$ for every $z\in \mathbb{C}$, then $f = bq$  for some $b\in \mathbb{C}$.

Can an arbitrary analytic function (on all of $\mathbb{C}$) replace $q$?

Comment: Please use mark-up. The edit to your previous question (which you still haven't adequately fixed) shows how.

Comment: You need absolute values around $q$ in your inequality.  Hint: Liouville.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really mean strict inequality, then this follows from [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29) applied to $f/q$. Note that $q$ must be constant too, as $q$ can have no zeros from the condition.

It is actually true if $<$ is replaced by $\leq$, though. (Maybe you meant this?) First, the Cauchy estimates show that $f$ is a polynomial; indeed, since $f$ grows polynomially, we can just take averages of $f/(z-\alpha)^N$ over larger and larger circles. From this one can see that $f$ is a polynomial.

Now the question reduces to showing that if a polynomial $p$ is bounded by a constant multiple of another polynomial $q$, then $p$ and $q$ differ by a constant. This is a straightforward consequence of factorization.

Comment: Good answer.  You could also apply Liouville's theorem without strict inequality, in conjunction with the fact that an analytic function has isolated zeros and a singularity of a bounded function is removable.

Comment: Thank you so much Akhil and Jonas! I meant strict inequality, sorry about that.