# An entire function $f$ obeys the estimate $|f(z)|\leq me^{\alpha x}$ for all points $z=x+iy$, where $m$ and $\alpha$ are positive constants. Verif

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, functions

**An entire function $f$ obeys the estimate $|f(z)|\leq me^{\alpha x}$ for all points $z=x+iy$, where $m$ and $\alpha$ are positive constants. Verify that $f$ has the form $f(z)=Ae^{\alpha z}$ for some constan A. Could one draw the same conclusion if one knew only that $|f(z)|\leq me^{\alpha |z|}$ held for every $z$?**

I am trying to solve this problem using the following:

[Property of Entire Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52121/property-of-entire-functions)

I know that $|me^{\alpha z}|=me^{\text{Re}(\alpha z)}=me^{\alpha x}$ and so $|f(z)|\leq |me^{\alpha z}|$ with which by the above post $f(z)=cme^{\alpha z}$, then $f(z)=Ae^{\alpha z}$ where $A:=cm$. Is this reasoning correct? Thank you very much.

How to answer the question they ask in the exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one you could alternatively say:
\begin{align}
\bigg|\frac{f(z)}{ e^{\alpha z}}\bigg| \leq m
\end{align}
Since $e^{\alpha z}$ is nonzero. So we have $f(z) e^{-\alpha z}$ is enitre as well. So by Liouville we have:
\begin{align}
f(z)e^{-\alpha z} = A
\end{align}
Hence:
\begin{align}
f(z) = Ae^{\alpha z}
\end{align} 
The second one is not true. Take $f(z)=1$ and you have:
\begin{align}
1 \leq e^{|z|}
\end{align}
For  $m=1$ and $\alpha=1$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your reasoning is correct. To give an explicit answer, condsider the entire function

$$
g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{me^{\alpha \cdot z}}
$$

By hypothesis, $|g(z)| \leq 1$, and so applying Liouville's theorem, $g(z)$ must be constant. This answers the first question.  As for the second one, $f = 1$ is a counterexample with $m = \alpha = 1$.