# Find all entire function such that $|f(z)| \leq |ze^z|$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

What I did is:
$f$ has zero at $0$, so $f(z)=zg(z)$.

Using the data, we can say $\frac{g(z)}{e^z}$ is constant.

So, $f(z)=Cze^z$. Is that correct?

Comment: What does “using the data” mean?

Comment: And not all $C$ will work.

Comment: $\frac{zg(z)}{ze^z}\leq 1$, So $\frac{g(z)}{e^z}\leq 1$, So $\frac{g(z)}{e^z}$ is a constant function.

Comment: why are you saying it?

Comment: If $C=2$ then $|f(z)|=2|ze^z|>|ze^z|$

Comment: That is in no way “using data.” Your answer should include that comment, not the vague “using the data.” State which theorem applies.

Comment: Note that this is a special case of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52121/42969.

Comment: Again, clarity. “Why are you saying it?” is unclear. What is “it.”

Comment: Doubts cleared @ThomasAndrews.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fleshing out the steps: substituting $z=0$ gives $|f(0)|\le0$ so $f(0)=0$; since $f$ is entire (Taylor series expansion valid over all complex plane), $f(z)=zg(z)$ for another entire function $g$. Then for $z\ne0$:
$$|f(z)|=|z||g(z)|\le|z||e^z|$$
$$|g(z)/e^z|=|g(z)e^{-z}|\le1$$
and $g(z)/e^z$ is entire bounded, so constant by Liouville's theorem. Hence $f(z)=cze^z$; the original condition forces $|c|\le1$.